# Bounce rate suddenly increased after changing tracking code to universal

Tags: google-analytics

My one site used classic tracking code for years without any problem, 3 days ago I replaced classic tracking code with universal. After replacing I see last 2 days suddenly my bounce rate was increased 2% to 79%.

Need expert advice, any possible way to find why this happening?

Comment: One site you mean signe page website or one of hundreads websites you own? Did u use cookie transition parameter during migration? Is bounce rate same all days or it is going down slowly? What is amount of returning visitors?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I mean one of some site. Actually I am confused about cookie transition parameter, is there any way to check? I am using GA for years and average bounce rate was 2%, now increasing after replace code from last 3 days its stuck on 78%. Average daily visitor 5000-8000 and 20% of them returning visitor.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking in a bad way. 2% Is very very low. I actually don't know any website having such a low bounce rate. Maybe that 78% is your real bounce rate and that 2% were caused by some automatic event without non-interaction flag. Do you have any automatic events on your page? Or event which is very easy to reach? 
'

Comment: No I am not using any automatic system, its a WordPress blog. please check 2 screenshot one for bounc rate and another pageview http://i.imgur.com/1UBirz8.jpg   http://i.imgur.com/OGy7KfL.jpg. Also I checked my adsense account and there not found anything wrong, average page view around 18K still remain same but its only affected on GA. There showing page view now 8k -9k, if you see few days ago it was around 16-18k. so after changing code its affected on 2 thing page view showing wrong and bounce rate. Thank you for helping me

Comment: It seems you had originally doubled pageview tracking somehow and now it is ok.